# ASP.NET FileDependency caching not working when accessing the page

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically what I want to do is a full server-side caching, and disable client-side caching.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
public ActionResult getImage(string imagePath)
{
    Response.AddFileDependency(imagePath);
    return base.File(imagePath, "image/jpg");
}
```

The caching works perfectly when 'Refreshing' the page. 
It returns "status: 304 Not-Modified", and switches to "status: 200" when manually changing the file.

However, when rendering the page by accessing from another page by hyperlink (RedirectToAction), or render page by clicking the url bar and pressing enter, it returns "status: 200 (cache)" even though the file has changed.

I tried combinations of

- Response.Cache.SetETagFromFileDependencies();
- Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();
- Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
- Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["If-None-Match"] = true;

but nothing worked.

Will be great if someone could lead me to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

```
public ActionResult getImage(string imagePath)
{
    return EtagFix(System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(imagePath).ToString(), HttpCacheability.Public, TimeSpan.FromHours(0)) ?? base.File(imagePath, "image/jpg");
}

ActionResult EtagFix(string etagResponse, HttpCacheability cachability, TimeSpan maxAge)
{
    var cache = Response.Cache;
    cache.SetETag(etagResponse);
    cache.SetMaxAge(maxAge);
    cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

    if (!etagResponse.Equals(Request.Headers["If-None-Match"])) return null;

    Response.StatusCode = 304;
    Response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Utilized source
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2011/06/16/mvc-always-returns-status-code-200-when-a-max-age-is-set-while-it-can-return-with-304.aspx